# anchor text onclick to c# function

Tags: c#, javascript, iframe, attributes, refresh

i have an iframe that which source need to be updated and refreshed. the way i want to do it is to click on an  and with it's onclick function, i need to send something like myiframe.Attributes["src"] = "blah.aspx";

is there any quick way to do this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript to send an AJAX query back to the server with the frame's source.

The javascript you could use is `iframe.location.href` where 'iframe' is the `id` attribute of your iframe.

Then you can send a callback to the server using ASP.NET AJAX (or another ajax call if you wish). Here is a good tutorial: http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could do it all client side if you wanted to (untested code):

```
...
<body>

    <a id="yourAnchorId">Load It</a>

    <iframe id="youriFrameId" src="blank.html" width="500" height="400"></iframe>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        document.getElementById('yourAnchorId').onclick = function() {
            var frame = document.getElementById('youriFrameId')
            frame.src = "blah.aspx;"
            frame.location.reload();
        };

    </script>

</body>
...
```

Comment: This would work as long as you knew what the target url was. If you need to generate the target URL programmatically, you could use this and AJAX to get the result.

Comment: thanks guys... both solutions worked fine :) i used the one using ajax.